# Change third party activity's name android

Tags: android, zendesk

I am using zopim sdk for chatting in my application and I am trying to change the title of my chat activity. I customized the title string like this and rebuilt my project:

```
 <string name="chat_activity_title">My Custom Title</string>
```

And when checked manifest of zopim in build folder it reflected there like this.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.zopim.android.sdk.prechat.ZopimChatActivity"
            android:label="My Custom Title"
            android:theme="@style/ZopimChatTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-1000" >
                <action android:name="zopim.action.RESUME_CHAT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But still when I run my app it always showing previous title why?
Is there anything I am missing?

(I am tagging zendesk here because they give support for the same)*

Comment: can you check the actual source for the active activity/fragment if there is something calling getActionBar().setTitle("") or something like that.?

Comment: did you tried cleaning your project ?

Comment: Maybe add the activity itself (ZopimChatActivity)

Comment: @Darkie I cleaned my project hell lot of time.

Comment: @DanielBo checked already and no.

Comment: tried to grep the title that is displayed in the sources?

Comment: @DanielBo I greped title and found this string only and that's why label changed.

Comment: restarted system? tried running gradle clean installDebug after restart? Multiple Versions of your project?

Answer (score 1):

### Please try this:

Please try to replace

```
tools:replace="android:theme, android:label"
```